# picasso error android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView

Tags: android, picasso

I understand its because my list_item.xml but what is the reason

I am getting this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
E/AndroidRuntime(27089):    at com.example.jsn.ImageListAdapter.getView(ImageListAdapter.java:44)
```

this is my code

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (null == convertView) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        Picasso
            .with(context)
            .load(imageUrls[position])
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher) // can also be a drawable
            .fit() // will explain later
            .noFade()
            .into((ImageView) convertView);  
        return convertView; // I guess here is my problem

    } 
}
```

this is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f0f0f0">

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/ImageView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="200dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

it works when I my list_item.xml like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ImageView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="200dp"/>
```

but why ? how to make it work with relativelayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `convertView` is the result of `inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);` which means it is an instance of the root element of `list_item.xml`, i.e. a `RelativeLayout`.

To fix this, you need to do the following:

```
    Picasso 
        .with(context) 
        .load(imageUrls[position])
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher) // can also be a drawable
        .fit() // will explain later 
        .noFade() 
        .into((ImageView) convertView.findViewbyId(R.id.ImageView));
```

Comment: oh  I didnt notice that , and I leave the inflater like this right ?

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

Comment: Yes, you can leave the inflater as is.